# Image name and extension

Tags: java, image, byte, blob

I am about developing a web application where I need to upload an image.
Now that an image is uploaded, can I get the image format and name from the file (represented in byte[] object) or I have to add columns that stores this information in my table as well.
Thanks for help.

Comment: If you take foo.jpg on your disk, and rename it to bar.jpg, does the content of the file change?

Comment: of course not, but what about the extension

Comment: So you have the answer to one of your question: you won't be able to find the file name in the contents of the file. Now for the type: assuming it's even possible to analyze the file bytes and deduce what the image type is, is it easier and faster to do that, or is it easier to store the file type in a database column directly?

Comment: that is what I am thinking about now, put the information in a database column both name and extension in their corresponding column

Answer (score 1):

Although databases are able to store large amount of bytes (BLOB) or characters (CLOB), it is not recommended for storing file data.

A better alternative is to store such files on the disk - as Kristjan also suggested in his answer - and store a reference to that file into the database. How the reference looks like depends on your application. It could be a path, it could be a number, or whatever your application needs to read the information and then locate the file.

Answer (score 0):

Better save image files as files on disk and not in database.